# Woocommerce swap Company name and Name

Tags: woocommerce

Does anyone know whether it's possible to swap the Company Name and the First+Last Name in the order details?
When filling out these elements they are the other way around and I would like them to stay that way.
I added a screenshot.

Thanks a lot.

[image: screenshot_orderdetails]

Comment: The code for this can be found in the following file https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L320 
however, there is no hook provided for changing the order of the fields. 
Correctly overwriting core files would lead you far too far, so I think if you really want this, you'd better swap fields with jQuery

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to work around it, it sounds a bit too complicated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end Woocommerce helped me out. Here you can read the solution:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/swap-company-and-name-field-in-order-backend/#post-12484747